# How to use colspan in gridview using ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, c#-3.0

I am using a grid view to show data on aspx page where I want to use colspan in between records as diffrentiator based on a forecolor or code. And in colspan want to put a text inside that i have attached dummy image:

[image]

Here is my code

```
DataTable dt = grd1.ToDataTable(objList);
grd1.DataBind(dt );

foreach (GridViewRow row in grd1.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < grd1.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        TableCell cell = row.Cells[i];
        cell.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["Color"]));
    }
}
```

Suppose there is four records and i want to put the differentiator between records based on a value from data records itself e.g i have 'Code' data record in data. so records with Code 1 will be together then with Code 2 will be separated by colspan.

Can anybody help me with this, please? Thanks in advance

Comment: For non-uniform tables, it would probably be easier to use [the `ListView` control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview?view=netframework-4.8) instead. That gives you complete control over the rendered markup.

Comment: @RichardDeeming i can't use that i want it in Gridview only